# UI looks different on different machines

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-7, windows-server-2008-x64

A part of the GUI of the software I'm working renders correctly on my computer with Windows 7 32 bit and renders wrong on another computer that has Windows Server 2008 64 bit. Here's how it looks on my computer:

[image: The correct rendering on my computer.]

And here's how it looks on the other computer:

[image]

The controls that render wrong are all in a `SplitConatiner`, the rest renders correctly on both machines. What can be the reason?

Comment: does both machines has graphics drivers installed?